# Client certificate is not being validate in webhook handshake

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, certbot

I'm trying to configure an Webhook for my application
but the ssl it not being validating.

this error occurs when i;m trying to call the endpoint

```
2023/08/08 22:52:08 [info] 22#22: *54 client SSL certificate verify error: (21:unable to verify the first certificate) while reading client request headers, client: 34.193.116.226, server: URL, request: "POST / HTTP/1.1", host: "URL"
```

this is my config of NGINX file

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  server {
    server_name host;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/client_cert_error.log debug;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/privkey.pem;

    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/chain-prod.crt;
    ssl_verify_client optional;
    ssl_verify_depth 3;

    location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index index.html;
    }


    # Configurar o servidor para encaminhar as solicitações para a API Node.js
    location /api/ {

      proxy_pass http://host:3000/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_ssl_server_name on;
      proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
      proxy_ssl_verify off;
    }

    **location /webhook { // THE PROBLEM IS HERE.
      if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
        return 403;
      }
      proxy_pass http://host:3000/;
    }**
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name host;
    location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index index.html;
    }
    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
      allow all;
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
  }

}
```

the location /webhook  always send me status 403, and the logs the messages above are being saved.

The certificates is in the correct path.